# How to create a switch case dynamically from database in PHP?

Tags: php, switch-statement

my question is to create this in PHP is easy:

```
switch ($var) {
    case 1:
        $foo = "test";
        break;
    case 2:
        $foo = "test1";
        break;
    case 3:
        $foo = "test2";
        break;
}
```

How can I dynamically create it with database data?

The idea is to stay as follows:

```
switch ($var) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        case $row['mydata1'] :
            $foo = $row['mydata2'];
            break;
    }
}
```

is this possible?

Comment: You could dynamically build a `.php` file and then execute that file.  Essentially you're talking about writing code that generates code, which itself expresses the intended logic.  You'd need to separate those two steps.  The idea seems filled with potential problems though, and should only be used when you're clearly building code-generating tools and not when just trying to compare values.  Why are you trying to do this at all?  Why not just compare values with `if` statements within your loop?

Comment: thanks for answering @David I have in my code a switch with 10 possible cases, it seemed more optimal to use a switch than 10 if. Now I have to do the same in 5 different places, it seemed more optimal to have a database with everything and in the code the same function for everyone, in case of not using the data from the database, I have to put the 10 cases of the switch in the 5 different sites.
I do not know if I explained well

Comment: If you loop through it, there is only one if.

Comment: @RubenAmezcua: You can still use a database and still loop through your values, just compare those values in an `if` condition instead of trying to build a `switch` like this.  It sounds like you're mixing up two different problems, one of trying to use dynamic values and one of trying to use a `switch`.  Solve the former problem, the latter is immaterial.

Comment: @David My idea was to use a switch but I will try the if and at the end I tell you if it works correctly

Comment: @invalidbot The appropriate value is read from a csv file.

Comment: You mean, the `$var` is read from a CSV file?

Comment: @invalidbot Yes.

Comment: One more question, in MySQL database, the field `myData1` and `myData2` stored in a same row or different rows? Also, what 's the value of `$var`?

Comment: @invalidbot They are different rows, for example the first one can have a mobile number and the second one can have the name of that person. $ var reads a mobile number from the csv and compares it on the switch case, if it matches, it returns the person's name.
(although right now I have put test, test1 ...)

Comment: I m confused! Can you please show how the data is being stored in MySQL and your expected output? Also, the value of `$var`.

Comment: @invalidbot $var reads a mobile number from the csv and compares it on the switch case, if it matches, it returns the person's name. (although right now I have put test, test1, test2... and where it says case 1, case2, case3 ... the real thing would be 666666666, 777777777 etc.) In the database I would like to have a column with the mobile numbers and another with the names, so when reading the mobile number of the csv instead of comparing with the manually written switch with all its cases, I want the switch to be created Automatically with database numbers.  You've understood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the lengthy comments on the question above, what you're looking for is a `while` loop and an `if` condition:

```
$foo = '';  // or some default value incase no match is found
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row['mydata1'] == $var) {
        $foo = $row['mydata2'];
        break;
    }
}
```

It's not clear why you really want a `switch` here, but it seems like you're just very much over-thinking the process.  At a logical level what you're trying to do is:

- Loop through a set of records
- Compare them with a variable

That's a loop and a conditional statement.  There's no need to overcomplicate this by trying to dynamically generate static code structures.  Just loop over your records and compare them with your value.

Comment: I have already tried it and it works, it is not with a switch but now I understand what you mean, it works for me